# Mount NTFS drive with Win10 installed is readonly

Tags: filesystems, mount, kali-linux

I mount 4 NTFS drives to linux "c: d: e: f:", the access for "d: e: f:" are read-write, only the "c:" is readonly, there is a Windows10 installed on "c:".

in /etc/fstab, they are mounted in the same way, but in FileManager there is a lock icon on "c:"

How to mount "c" read-write automatically?

Environment: Kali linux, release 2020.1, root user

```
UUID=34B079F8B079C0C2 /c ntfs defaults 0 0
UUID=0C5B0DB10C5B0DB1 /d ntfs defaults 0 0
UUID=110D17B6110D17B6 /e ntfs defaults 0 0
UUID=0E5219E00E5219E0 /f ntfs defaults 0 0
```

I tried `mount -o remount rw /c`, after that the lock icon on "/c" disappeared. But I still cannot create file/dir in "/c":

```
/c ❯ mkdir aaa
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘aaa’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: That usually happens if you do not disable fast shutdown and/or hibernation on newer windows versions (since at least 8.1). Have a look at https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/#fastrestart
If you shutdown windows properly without hibernating, you should be able to mount it read-write.

Comment: This works, run the command `powercfg /h off` in Windows solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may install `ntfs-3g` and then use the following line in `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID=34B079F8B079C0C2 /c ntfs-3g defaults,auto,nls=utf8,umask=000,dmask=027,fmask=137,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names 0 0
```

(including auto mounting at boot).
Reboot your system.

Also disable fast startup, e.g. [this](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup) or [this](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001762.htm).

Comment: I tried use this line in the `/etc/fstab` and reboot, the lock icon in FileManager is gone, but it's still read-only. I cannot create file in /c

Comment: @aj3423 - A couple of feedback questions:
1. So yo uhad to install `ntfs-3g`?
2. Did you disable [fast startup](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup)?
3. Please post the exact command you run (I suggest `touch /c/testfile.txt`) and the exact message you get.

Comment: Yes I have `ntfs-3g`, I try to install via `apt install ntfs-3g`, it says *ntfs-3g is already the newest version (1:2017.3.23AR.3-3)*, and `ntfs-3g` is available in terminal command. When the **fast startup** is not disabled, I cannot write to "/c", no matter with `ntfs` or `ntfs-3g`. After **fast startup** is disabled, both `ntfs` and `ntfs-3g` works. I think the key is **fast startup**

Comment: @aj3423 - Great. I will update the answer. Will later remove cluttering comments.